# Is there any limitation for Reading Quran completely during one day?

Tags: quran, reading-quran

Is there any limitation for Complete reading Al-Quran (Khatim) during one day for example? if so, what is the best time-table for reading Al-Quran that acceptable and allowed?

Answer (score 2):

It is best to read the quran with understanding and contemplation. If you read the whole quran in a day, then it CAN be that you are not reading it, as it should be read.

You can read the quran at almost anytime and place, you want.

Comment: It is a great point as you pointed out "It is best to read the quran with understanding and contemplation" Hopefully we note it.

Answer (score 1):

It is said that the holy Quran should be read part (Ayah) for part (Ayah).

For example, you get the best meal in the world, but your mouth only allows you to eat it bite for bite, as you have to chew it, you taste it, and in a compared manner, you have to read the holy Kuran part for part, trying to understand the meaning and taste his words' meaning.

Answer (score 1):

The point of reading the Quran is to understand and apply it,  The Prophet (صلى الله عليه و سلم) said:

> لَمْ يَفْقَهْ مَنْ قَرَأَ الْقُرْآنَ فِي أَقَلَّ مِنْ ثَلاَثٍ
>
> He who recites the Qur'an in less than three (days), he does not
>   understand it

[Jami'i Tirmidhi](http://sunnah.com/urn/631960)

So if one wants to read the whole Quran, one should do it in no less then three days, though there were scholars in the past who used to read the whole Quran in one day.  Though depending on the understanding a person may have, plus the amount of time they may have to sit and read, it may take longer then three days to read the whole Quran.  So in the end, the Quran should be read at least in one month.

Sources: [Hadith 1](http://sunnah.com/abudawud/6/18), [Hadith 2](http://sunnah.com/abudawud/6/20)