# Is it recommended to complete reading the Quran once in Ramadan?

Tags: ramadan, reading-quran

Is it mustahabb (recommended) to complete reading the Quran once in Ramadan? Please support your answer with references.

Comment: I don't think there's a clear or hadith with a litteral order or recommendation, but you might find ahadith indicating it being recommended even each months, but this is only a comment because i need to check my claim.

Comment: @Sassir I think that is what you referred to http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/9055/is-there-any-limitation-for-reading-quran-completely-during-one-day?rq=1 see also http://sunnah.com/bukhari/30/85, http://sunnah.com/abudawud/6/25, http://sunnah.com/nasai/22/311, http://sunnah.com/urn/731920, http://sunnah.com/muslim/13/238 and http://sunnah.com/urn/1314070 ... Scholars say that the quran should be completed at least each two months. And one should do more efforts in Ramadan. And it's better to read it with tajweed and again much better is reading and reflecting/understanding.

Comment: I m satisfied with the 2 answers given below but which one should i tick mark since both are deserving ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All Praise to Allah Subhanahu wa Taala and blessings of Him be on Prophet Muhammad peace be upon him His family and companions

Yeah is is Mustahab and Sunnah to read the Quran in the month of ramadan as it is following the way of Prophet Muhammad peace be upon him.He used to revise the  Quran with Angel Gabriel(AS) during the month of Ramadan.

> Narrated Ibn `Abbas: The Prophet (ﷺ) was the most generous of all the
>   people, and he used to become more generous in Ramadan when Gabriel
>   met him. Gabriel used to meet him every night during Ramadan to revise
>   the Qur'an with him. Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) then used to be more
>   generous than the fast wind.(Bukhari)

And

> Narrated `Aisha: Once Fatima came walking and her gait resembled the
>   gait of the Prophet (ﷺ) . The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "Welcome, O my
>   daughter!" Then he made her sit on his right or on his left side, and
>   then he told her a secret and she started weeping. I asked her, "Why
>   are you weeping?" He again told her a secret and she started laughing.
>   I said, "I never saw happiness so near to sadness as I saw today." I
>   asked her what the Prophet (ﷺ) had told her. She said, "I would never
>   disclose the secret of Allah's Messenger (ﷺ)." When the Prophet (ﷺ)
>   died, I asked her about it. She replied. "The Prophet (ﷺ) said: 'Every
>   year Gabriel used to revise the Qur'an with me once only, but this
>   year he has done so twice. I think this portends my death, and you
>   will be the first of my family to follow me.' So I started weeping.
>   Then he said. 'Don't you like to be the chief of all the ladies of
>   Paradise or the chief of the believing women? So I laughed for
>   that."(Bukhari).

Allah Swt and His Messenger knows best.

Answer (score 2):

As servant pointed out we should follow the sunnah of the Prophet (peace be upon him) and do our best to read the quran, especially in Ramadan as we know that it's [the month of the quran](http://legacy.quran.com/2/185). But even if we know that our Messenger (peace be upon him) used to [study the quran](https://islamqa.info/en/26327) with Jibreel each Ramadan and in his last Ramadan he has been revised twice. There's no clear order to read it completely, as in the Ramadans before the revelation may not have been completed yet as it seems and Allah knows best, assuming this that would mean that only in his last Ramadan he had revised the whole (actual) quran (as the revelation only ended a few days before the prophet's death)!
 For this reason scholars tend to say that it is not a sunnah to complete it neither at Qiyam prayer nor at day in Ramadan.

But it is well known that we should do our best to complete it each month, or every 40 days, or every 20 days, every 15 days, 7 days or, at most in 3 days according to a lot of ahadith which you may find in the comments and the [link about the limitation](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/9055/is-there-any-limitation-for-reading-quran-completely-during-one-day?lq=1). Because 3 days is the minimum amount to read and understand it, even if it has been reported about many sahaba and tabi'yn and salaf that they had read it completely in less then that time.

But it is indeed mustahab to read and study the quran a great deal during this month. Note that reading may mean reading and understanding and if possible with tajweed. For example Qatada according [this source](http://www.nquran.com/index.php?group=view&rid=3064) (Arabic) used to complete the quran in any other month in 7 days and in Ramadan in only 3 of them and in the last 10 nights in each night of them, while Ibrahimn an-Nakha'i used to read (complete) it every 3 days and in the last 10 nights in each second night.

See also this [fatwa](https://islamqa.info/en/65754), where you may find

> Shaykh Ibn ‘Uthaymeen (may Allaah have mercy on him) was asked: Is it
> obligatory for the fasting person to complete the Qur’aan in Ramadaan?
>
> He replied:
>
> Completing the Qur’aan in Ramadaan is not obligatory for the fasting
> person, but he should read the Qur’aan a great deal in Ramadaan, as
> that is the Sunnah of the Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of
> Allaah be upon him), and he (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon
> him) used to review it with Jibreel every Ramadaan. End quote.

If you can read Arabic take also a look in [this thread](http://www.sahab.net/forums/index.php?showtopic=104408) quoting statements of scholars on the matter.

And not that among the [best deeds](https://islamqa.info/en/26242) is:

> Persisting in acts of worship even if they are little