# Can we read selected surhas during tarhaveeh?

Tags: taraweeh, reading-quran

I'm a student we are start [traveeh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarawih) in our hostel.  Can we read selected surhas in traveeh or not？  It has some conditions in Islam or not?

Comment: Welcome to Islam.SE! Questions are expected to be specific, on topic, and with some research done prior to asking. Please refer to [how to ask a question](//islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), and take a [tour](//islam.stackexchange.com/tour) in our [help center](//islam.stackexchange.com/help). I do not understand your question. What do you mean by "selected surahs"? Are you trying to say which surahs can be recited in _taraweeh_ prayers? Any verses from the Qur'an can be recited.

Comment: You can pray taraweeh even if you know Fatiha(chapter 1) and 2 other surahs. There is no condition for any prayer that unique surahs are to be recited. Inshallah if you dont know other surahs other than Fatiha pray only Fatiha in those units, your prayer will be accepted.

Comment: Related verdict: https://islamqa.info/en/6422

Comment: https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/31422/reading-the-quran-in-ramadan/31427#31427