# How much of the Qur'an is recommended to be read, to compete khatmah during Ramadan

Tags: ramadan, reading-quran

It's Sunnah to make a complete reading of the Qur'an during Ramadan. And Jibreel would revise the Qur'an with Muhammad ﷺ every Ramadan.

I remember being told at one point, in order to complete the Qur'an during Ramadan you should read a whole juz every day. https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/31426/43

However there are 30 Juz and between 29 and 30 days during Ramadan.

How many juz (if any) is one recommended to read over day, if Ramadan might be 29 days?

I know some companions would complete the Qur'an in 3 days, but I'm not yet able to do that.

Comment: You want to have one complete khatmah then you should read at least one juz'  or two hours a day and to be sure to complete the Qur'an within Ramadan you could simply read a quarter of a hot (robo' or rob') more in the last ten days...

Comment: @Medi1Saif is that what's recommended in the Sunnah of the Prophet ﷺ? Also I'm unfamiliar with those units. Please do make an answer explaining more!

Comment: There is no explanation in the Sunnah of how much to read everyday afaik.

Comment: These devisions of the qur'an didn't exist at the time of the propeht() in fact juz' in Arabic only means a piece of (it might be defined or not). These divisions were initiated by the Omayyad governer al-Hajjj ibn Yusuf a-Thaqafi who is often regarded as a tyran by historians and are therefore not present in the sunnah. If you want to complete the qur'an in Ramadan you should at least read it from surat al-Fatihah to surat an-Nas once if you started a new khatmah it is fine.